# How to pre-filter a Jquery Filterable portfolio

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, portfolio

I apologize if this is a basic question.  I am using a Jquery filterable portfolio and want use it to more or less look like a book.  By this I mean showing page 1 when the page loads, then allow the users to scroll to other pages using the sort at the top of the page.

The problem I am having is that when the page loads, by default all of the pages are showing.  How do I make it so that only the 1st page shows when the page loads?  I have tried adding the hidden attribute to the `<li>` tags, but then they don't return when the filters are called.

Here is the code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills sort-source" data-sort-id="portfolio" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li data-option-value=".page1" class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li data-option-value=".page2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li data-option-value=".page3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="row">

    <ul class="portfolio-list sort-destination" data-sort-id="portfolio">
                        <li class="span12 isotope-item page1">
                            Page 1
                        </li>
                        <li class="span12 isotope-item page2">
                            Page 2
                        </li>
                            <li class="span12 isotope-item page3">
                            Page 3
                        </li>
                    </ul></div>
```

The portfolio code is just the standard one that comes with the bootstrap.  I have made no change.

Answer (score 0):

You could css it

```
portfolio-list li{ 
    display: none;
}
portfolio-list li:first-child{ 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi Martijn.  Thanks for the contribution.  Unfortunately that did not work.  It hid page 2 and page 3 as expected, but when I clicked on page 2 or 3 they came up but were still not displaying.

Comment: Do you know how bootstrap goes to the next one? Press forward once, and backwards once. Find out what the difference is compared to your initial loading and make those match :)